# Libdx - Drawing NinePatch on Box2d

Tags: java, libgdx, nine-patch

I am trying to draw a NinePatch on a Box2d body. I got it to work for sprites but no luck with NinePatch.

This is what I got to draw sprite on top of the body.

```
playerSprite.setSize(radius * 2, radius * 2);
playerSprite.setOrigin(playerSprite.getWidth() / 2, playerSprite.getHeight() / 2);

void draw(Batch batch){
    playerSprite.setPosition(player.getPosition().x-playerSprite.getWidth()/2, player.getPosition().y - playerSprite.getHeight()/2);
    playerSprite.setRotation(player.getAngle() * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees);
    playerSprite.draw(batch);
}
```

Comment: And where's the code you've tried with `NinePatch`?